# unable to get object3D in scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am unable to get Object3D from the scene. Although the mesh objects are shown in scene. The scene.children array does not show that.
Please have a look at the screenshot (link).

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvfslx5kxwlv0ec/threejsHelp.jpg?dl=0)

Code:

```
function init(){
loadJSON(function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
    materialType = ['MeshBasicMaterial','MesLambertMaterial','MeshPhongMaterial', 'MeshStandardMaterial'];

    for (var i =0; i< jsonData.materials.length; i++){
        var matName = jsonData.materials[i].name;
        materialArray[matName] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
        materialArray[matName].name = matName;
    }
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.models.length;i++){
        parentGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
        parentGroup.name = jsonData.models[i].name;
        for(var j = 0; j < jsonData.models[i].children.length;j++){
            childName = jsonData.models[i].children[j].name;
            matType = jsonData.models[i].children[j].material;

            loader.load( "models/" + childName, makeHandler( childName , materialArray[matType],parentGroup), false ); 

        }
        scene.add(parentGroup);
    }
    });//loadJSON
    console.log(scene.children); //-- SCREENSHOT OUTPUT --

}//init function

// HANDLER FUNCTION
function makeHandler(meshName, material,parentObj) { 
    return function(geometry) { 
    object3d = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material); 
    object3d.name = meshName;
    parentObj.add(object3d);
    };
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the part of your code that tries to get those item?

Comment: Just added the code.. thanks.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you give us the error code (if any) and highlight the relevant line in the code.

Comment: There is no error code, only thing it displays is 'undefined' when trying to access the desired mesh object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loader.load()` is an asynchronous function call. That is why you specify a callback function.

In your case, you are calling `console.log( scene.children )` before the models load, and before the models are added to the scene.

three.js r.77

Comment: So any suggestion as to how to go about. Thanks. moreover right now the same code seems to be working. But on refreshing the page  it doesn't show the children, in the array.

Comment: I suggest you continue to familiarize yourself with Javascript.